# Python can save number/string in variables. Then, is it possible to save number and string in one variable together?

Tags: python

Python can save number/string in variables. Is it then possible to save a number and string in one variable together?  If yes, Can you show me an example?

Comment: What do you mean, "together"? How about `tup = (3, "three")`?

Comment: What do you mean by "save number and string in one variable together"? Are you asking whether a variable can have more than one object _assigned_ to it, or just whether you can somehow store more than one object in a variable?

Answer (score 3):

Python can hold only one object at a time in a variable. The object can be an array , number , string , boolean. If you are looking to hold 2 or more values then you should look into lists,dictionaries,tuples.

```
tuple =(1,"string",3)
list =[1,2,"string"]
dictionary = {"string":1}
```

Dictionary is a bit different since it works with key and value pairs.

Comment: After all, it's Schrödinger's cat, not Schrödinger's snake.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you have a number of options here, I will expand on user655941's answer.

The first option you have is using lists, dictionaries and tuples as he mentioned, you are able to mix any kind of data structures, including other lists and tuples, in any order you want.

The second option which might be of interest is using classes if you want to do more with your stored data, for example (code taken from W3schools):

```
class Person:
  def __init__(self, name, age):
    self.name = name
    self.age = age

p1 = Person("John", 36)

print(p1.name)
print(p1.age)
```

And you can additionally add extra functions to a class if needed. Depending on your needs for the data storage, this might be more (or less) useful to you.